# What's the best way to delete a previously .gitignored file from other machines?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a project which, upon startup, copies one of three files A,B,C from one place to another (depends on project configs). This copied file X is .gitignored and always has the same name, and only the original files A,B,C are committed to git. I am now removing this copying logic, and need to make sure this .gitignored file X gets deleted from others' machines. What's the best way to do this?

I have a few ideas so far:

1. **Keep the .gitignore and don't delete the file** *(messy, I don't want to do this)*
2. **Update the project startup logic to always delete the file if it exists, then remove that logic after a few weeks when it has run on most developer machines and send messaging to tell others to delete it if they see it** *(a little odd, but this matches how the file was created on all other machines in the first place. having to send messaging isn't ideal though)*
3. **Commit the file, then delete the file** *(this could work, but it feels odd. 1) I don't know how this would work on all developer machines since we're adding then deleting a file that was already there ignored, 2) different machines have different versions of this file and I don't want to mess up history)*.

Has anyone else run into this type of issue and know if there's an obvious best answer? I'm looking for what is easiest both for deployment machines (file is actually deleted) and for all of our developer machines (people don't have to deal with some new untracked file that just pops up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the three ideas you listed, #2 is the only one that achieves the goal.

In particular, committing the file, then committing its removal, *does* work under *one particular condition:* that others check out the commit in which the file exists, then check out any commit in which the file does not exist.  The first step—which may require that they *also* bypass Git's objection about clobbering an untracked file—puts the extracted file into Git's index.  The subsequent switch to a commit in which the file *doesn't* exist is what makes Git *remove* the file: it's there in their working tree, and matches the index copy, and switching to the *other* commit says to remove the file, so Git removes the file that matches the index copy, while it's also removing the index copy.

Should other users of clones of this repository skip directly from commit `a123456` (or whatever hash ID it may be) that lacks the file, to the latest commit `b789abc` that continues to lack the file (even though intermediate commit `deadbeef` commits the file), their Git will continue to treat the tracked file in their working tree as an untracked file in their working tree.  If the file is no longer listed in `.gitignore` (in commit `b789abc`), their Git will subsequently *gripe* about the untracked file, but it won't *remove* it.

(This, by the way, is more evidence that Git is not a deployment system.  A deployment system would offer ways to create, delete, and/or archive this file X.)